# Has Ask Ubuntu turned into Ask Linux?

Tags: discussion

It seems that many of the questions asked on this site aren't just about Ubuntu, but about Linux in general.  Is this site meant to be only Ubuntu, or is it meant to be for any user of Linux?

Answer (score 7):

It's meant to be specifically about Ubuntu and all of its official derivates.

Of course many problems and questions about Ubuntu systems can also appear on similar distributions. Especially all the Debian based Linux systems are very similar in many aspects.

However, we try to close questions which are obviously not about Ubuntu and point the asking person over to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead, where all Linux distributions are welcome, without any restrictions.